# docker-pr proc already listening on port 80? Installed docker with snappy on Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, docker-run

I ran this:

```
docker run -ti -p 80:80 --name esproxy "$tag"
```

but I get this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   connectivity on endpoint esproxy
>   (ead1fa4f09b2326cd1ff6aa0e3b8f8bfa5c9d353eb6db4efef6d188b81ea9df7):
>   Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address
>   already in use.

So I did:

```
root@ip-172-xx-29-110:/interos/repos/nginx# lsof -i:80
```

and I got:

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 28213 root    4u  IPv6  64253      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

and so this process looks like:

```
root     28213  0.0  0.0 116552  2620 ?        Sl   04:34   0:00 /snap/docker/384/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 80 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 80
```

---

does anybody know what that process is?

Comment: Note that `docker-pr` is just `docker-proxy` truncated in the output.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue.

Stoppping all runing containers and restarting the docker service fixed it for me

`service docker restart`

and then start your container again

Answer (score 5):

If after you restart the docker service, the `docker-pr` service allocates some container port, your container is starting automatically.

To check if you have some container running use:

```
docker ps
```

To stop this container, we can use:

```
docker stop container_name
```

If you have more than one container, we can use:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

To stop a container from starting automatically, we need to remove it from the auto restart.

To do this use the following command:

```
docker update --restart=no container_name
```

After this, you will able to restart your docker service and you will not found any container starting automatically.